# Popup Window not closing onError - PayPal JS SDK

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I've been through the javascript SDK documentation but cannot find any reference to this. I'm simulating trying to capture a duplicate invoice id, so the OnError callback is being called. This is working correctly but the popup window persists and never closes.

Shouldn't the popup close? If this requires a bit of code - what might this be?

```
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                intent: "<%=ppacIntent%>",
                payer: {
                    name: {
                        given_name: pgplFirstName,
                        surname: pgplLastName
                    },
                    address: {
                        address_line_1: pgplAddress1,
                        address_line_2: pgplAddress2,
                        admin_area_2: pgplCity,
                        admin_area_1: pgplState,
                        postal_code: pgplPostalCode,
                        country_code: pgplCountry
                    },
                    email_address: pgplEmailAddress,
                    phone: {
                        phone_type: "MOBILE",
                        phone_number: {
                            national_number: pgplPhoneNumber
                        }
                    }
                },
                purchase_units: [{
                    invoice_id: "1188",//pgusOrderID,
                    amount: {
                        value: pgplOrderAmount,
                        currency_code: "<%=session("PPACCurrency")%>"
                    },
                    shipping: {
                        type: "SHIPPING",
                        name: {
                            full_name: pgplsFirstName + ' '+pgplsLastName
                        },
                        address: {
                            address_line_1: pgplsAddress1,
                            address_line_2: pgplsAddress2,
                            admin_area_2: pgplsCity,
                            admin_area_1: pgplsState,
                            postal_code:  pgplsPostalCode,
                            country_code: pgplsCountry
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.<%=ppacIntent%>().then(function (details) {
                
                rtnID = details.id;
                rtnStatus = details.status;
                rtnIntent = details.intent;
                rtnDetails = JSON.stringify(details);

                
            });
        },
        onCancel: function(data) {
            //customer cancelled
           
        },
        onError: function(err) {
            //error that prevents customer from checking out
             return actions.restart()
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: The onApprove callback should return, regardless of errors

Comment: It does, but has no error information. Using "onError: function(err) {..}" I can trap there's an error.  The issue is that the popup window stays open with the status circle spinning.  I need to know how to close it.

Comment: Apparently you are doing something wrong, but with no complete example to reproduce it's impossible to advise further on what you may be doing wrong. See the complete, working example in the standard integration guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ and a dynamically editable one at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I neglected to mention that this is for Advanced Checkout, not Standard.  I'm passing in an already used invoice_id to simulate the error.  I found "return actions.restart()" and added it to onError and it's now closing the popup.

Comment: Advanced checkout does not open popups, `actions` is only defined for standard (not advanced) payments, and actions.restart() should only be called for recoverable errors. But okay then.